# cool retro term & Ubuntu Apps all have Screen tearing

Tags: 22.04

I installed Ubuntu terminal through wsl2 correctly and everything is up to date but when I run cool-retro-term the thing opens and then displays a screen that is extremely torn.  best way to describe it is to see the image attached.  I also get this error code when I run

`cool-retro-term`

```
QStandardPaths: wrong permissions on runtime directory /run/user/1000/, 0755 instead of 0700
Both point size and pixel size set. Using pixel size.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you might have noticed, Qt wants that path to have 0700 has its permissions.

You can overwrite the path it looks by setting environment variable `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`.

For example:

```
$ cd ~
$ mkdir qpath
$ chmod 700 qpath
$ export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=$HOME/qpath
```

Then, try running `cool-retro-term` again. Hope it helps.

Obviously, if you want, you can add that `export` to your `.bashrc`.